# How to redirect url show modal in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I would like to print "redirect url" in modal as a result of receiving from curl after submit on the same page.
What should I do?

in this submit form code

```
<form method="post" id="kakao_pay" action="">
<input type="text" name="item_name" class="form-control"/>
</form>
```

in this curl code

```
if ($status_code == 200) {
$output_arr = json_decode($output, true);
$page = $output_arr['next_redirect_pc_url'];
echo "
<script>window.open('$page' , 'payviewer', 'width=450,height=500' );</script>
";
}
```

I want  "window.open('$page' , 'payviewer', 'width=450,height=500' );" change modal.

How to change?

Comment: What issue your are facing ?

Comment: @JohnDoe I want to hide the title bar. But you can't hide the title bar with the pop-up. So I want to use modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding HTML & PHP Code. Update it according to your desired requirement.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="kakao_pay" action="">
    <input type="text" name="item_name" class="form-control"/>
</form>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe id="iframe_modal" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 40%;"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
$status_code = 200;
if ($status_code == 200)
{
    $page = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/d7sewLjzNs0";
    ?>
    <script>
    var url = "<?php echo $page; ?>";
    $("#iframe_modal").attr("src", url);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```